# visible is not working on javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make my buttons visible and false based on conditions. I have tried the following. Its working only if the buttons are visible on page load

```
   if(count > 0)
   {
    document.getElementById('<%=msg.ClientID%>').innerHTML="Do you want to delete " + count + " record(s)?";
    document.getElementById('<%=btnNo1.ClientID%>').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('<%=btnYes1.ClientID%>').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('<%=btnNo1.ClientID%>').value="Cancel";
   }
   else
   {
   document.getElementById('<%=msg.ClientID%>').innerHTML="No records to delete";
   document.getElementById('<%=btnNo1.ClientID%>').style.visibility="visible";
   document.getElementById('<%=btnYes1.ClientID%>').style.visibility="hidden";
   document.getElementById('<%=btnNo1.ClientID%>').value="OK"
   }
```

is there any other solution

Comment: Since you seem to be generating this on the server, why not directly change the template?

Comment: Check if you have any JS errors logged in the console (DevTools or something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of visibility use display property

```
    if(count > 0)
   {
    document.getElementById('<%=msg.ClientID%>').innerHTML="Do you want to delete " + count + " record(s)?";
    document.getElementById('<%=btnNo1.ClientID%>').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('<%=btnYes1.ClientID%>').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('<%=btnNo1.ClientID%>').value="Cancel";
   }
   else
   {
   document.getElementById('<%=msg.ClientID%>').innerHTML="No records to delete";
   document.getElementById('<%=btnNo1.ClientID%>').style.display="block";
   document.getElementById('<%=btnYes1.ClientID%>').style.display="none";
   document.getElementById('<%=btnNo1.ClientID%>').value="OK"
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

For hiding..

```
document.getElementById('<%=btnNo1.ClientID%>').style.display="none";
```

For showing.,.

```
document.getElementById('<%=btnNo1.ClientID%>').style.display="block";
```

Answer (score 0):

In detail you can see from JQuery site : http://api.jquery.com/show/

When you need to hide these buttons then use it:

```
$("#btnNo1").hide();
$("#btnYes1").hide();
```

When you need to Show these buttons then use following:

```
$("#btnYes1").show();
$("#btnNo1").show();
```

Thanks.